# Show $(ab)^{1/n}=a^{1/n} b^{1/n}$ for any $a,b >0$ and $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

So, what I have in hand is the definition of the nth root of a real number, that is $y=x^{1/n}$ is the number that satisfies $y^n=x$. And I also have $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$, $a,b >0$.

How can I go from here to $(ab)^{1/n}=a^{1/n} b^{1/n}$?

I tried to write things like $ab=((ab)^n)^{1/n}$ using the definition. But I can only get $((ab)^n)^{1/n}=(a^n)^{1/n}(b^n)^{1/n}$ and I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a^{1/n}b^{1/n})^n=\underbrace{(a^{1/n}b^{1/n})\cdot(a^{1/n}b^{1/n})\cdot\cdot\cdot(a^{1/n}b^{1/n})}_{n\text{ times}}=\underbrace{(a^{1/n}\cdot\cdot\cdot a^{1/n})}_{n\text{ times}}\times\underbrace{(b^{1/n}\cdot\cdot\cdot b^{1/n})}_{n\text{ times}}=ab$

Answer (score 0):

Given $a\gt 0$, consider $f(x)=x^n-a$. If it has at least two distinct positive real roots, we may denote two of them by $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$. By Rolle's theorem, there is a number between the two roots, say $\beta$, such that the derivative $f'(\beta)=0$, in other words $n\beta^{n-1}=0$, a contradiction.

We take $a^{1/n}$ as the unique positive real root of $x^n-a=0$, $b^{1/n}$ that of $y^n-b=0$, and $(ab)^{1/n}$ that of $z^n-ab=0$. Then $z^n=ab=x^ny^n=(xy)^n$ and thus by the uniqueness of the root we have $(ab)^{1/n}=a^{1/n}b^{1/n}$.